# Invalid entries in Windows Bootloader

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, multi-boot

Something is wrong with my computer. On my Vista computer I installed windows 7.  Now when I start my computer it does a dual boot.  If I choose to run Vista it gives me an error. So, how do I just delete the Vista off my computer so its only Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Use **[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=642)** to delete the Vista entry.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what it should look like after you delete the entry (evil grin)?

Comment: Nuff said Molly! ;-) @paxdiablo: if you back it up you can delete whatever you want (just don't forget to restore the backup)!